# go webtransport app and nginx proxy not working

Tags: go, nginx, quic

I'm trying to run a go webtransport app on a Ubuntu server and access it via nginx over the web. nginx version is 1.25.1. But calling the app always results in 502 Bad Gateway.

The go code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/quic-go/quic-go/http3"
    "github.com/quic-go/webtransport-go"
)

var server = webtransport.Server{
    H3: http3.Server{Addr: ":5004"},
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        session, err := server.Upgrade(w, r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("upgrading failed: %s", err)
            w.WriteHeader(500)
            return
        }

        // handle session
    })

    _, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    fmt.Printf("cancel: %v\n", cancel)

    server.CheckOrigin = checkOrigin

    listenErr := server.ListenAndServeTLS("/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem")
    if listenErr != nil {
        log.Printf("error on listen and serve tls: %s", listenErr)
    }
}

func checkOrigin(r *http.Request) bool {
    return true
}
```

The nginx config file looks like this:

```
server {
 listen 443 quic reuseport;
 listen 443 ssl;

 server_name quic.mydomain.de;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/webtransport.access.log;

 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem;

 ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;

 quic_retry on;
 ssl_early_data on;

 location / {
  add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":$server_port"; ma=86400';
  proxy_pass         https://[::]:5004;

  add_header X-protocol $server_protocol always;
 }
}
```

The app is running, netstat output is

```
udp6    0    0 :::5004      :::*        24683/main
```

But nginx log says

```
[error] 15984#15984: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: quic.mydomain.de, request: "GET / HTTP/3.0", upstream: "https://[::]:5004/"
```

It is not clear to me what the problem is. Should this even work?

Comment: did you figure out the answer to this?

Comment: No, not so far.

Comment: thank for getting back

Answer (score 0):

The Nginx current version (1.25.3) is not support the Webtransport. It is just support the pure HTTP3 connections (I don't know any other widely used HTTP server which is support the Webtransport also).

Here the detailed reason of lack of Webtransport support in the Nginx:

The Webtransport is an extension of the HTTP3 protocol if you are interested in the details you can find here the whole documentation of the Webtransport protocol: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-webtrans-overview/

The section 3.2. Extended CONNECT in HTTP/3 describes how the Webtransport connection should be handled:

First, the Nginx doesn't advertise the Webtransport related settings:

- SETTINGS_ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL
- SETTINGS_H3_DATAGRAM

Second, the Nginx rejects the `CONNECT` HTTP method which should be required to initiate the Webtransport connection. See the reason in the commit: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/5f85bb3714a81d158f4d849ad5c61aec2737a9f0

Third, the Nginx doesn't handle the `:protocol` pseudo header which is also sent in the Webtransport protocol.

Furthermore, the Nginx HTTP3 datagram handling doesn't work with Webtransport datagrams. And that point, where I gave up the Nginx source code inspection, why it it doesn't support Webtransport.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your research results!